# C TCP Echo Server - Data displays only on close()

Tags: python, c, sockets, tcp

So, I was working on a TCP socket connection in C. I made an echo server, which uses getaddrinfo(), then bind(), listen(), accept and finally starts a while loop for receiving data until the client disconnects.

Here's the problem: The code apparently works, but the data received in the loop is displayed **ONLY** when the client disconnects. I wanted the data sended to the server to be displayed *while* the client is connected, like a simple chat. The data is sended, and the server sees it immediately.

So, here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(void) {

    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t addr_size;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;
    int sockfd, newfd;

    int numbytes;
    char buf[512];

    // first, load up address structs with getaddrinfo():

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;  // use IPv4 or IPv6, whichever
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;     // fill in my IP for me

    getaddrinfo(NULL, "7890", &hints, &res);

    // make a socket, bind it, and listen on it:

    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen);
    listen(sockfd, 1);

    // now accept an incoming connection:

    addr_size = sizeof(their_addr);
    newfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &addr_size);

    while((numbytes = recv(newfd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0)) > 0) {

        buf[numbytes] = '\0'; // sets the character after the last as '\0', avoiding dump bytes.
        printf("%s", buf);

    }

    return 0;
}
```

If this is relevant in any way, I'm running Linux. However, I noticed something. If I delete the loop, using the server to receive **only one** piece of data, the text shows immediately. I used a simple Python client to send the data, here's the code for the client:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1", 7890))
s.send("hey server!")
```

Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance to anyone who tries!

Comment: you might need to flush `stdout` with `fflush()` because io is buffered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examples for python send are of the following variety:

```
def mysend(self, msg):
    totalsent = 0
    while totalsent < MSGLEN:
        sent = self.sock.send(msg[totalsent:])
        if sent == 0:
            raise RuntimeError("socket connection broken")
        totalsent = totalsent + sent
```

The reason for that is **the data may not be sent until the socket is closed or a newline is encountered**.  See [Python Socket Programming HOW-TO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html#socket-howto) for more information

Comment: Thanks! The problem was **exactly** the newline. I added a '\n' into the C code and now the data flows correctly when its sended. Again, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why \n works is because the buffering is set or defaults to _IOLBUF.

See the function `setvbuf()` for an explanation of the different ways the buffer for a file (or STDOUT) can be managed.

Finally, as a note if you issue `fflush(stdout);` this forces the flushing of the buffer and is independent of what the value of a file's buffering flags.